# Search in Access Database table VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridviewcolumn

I have some problem to get data from table (ms-access databse) to show in my searchbox.text.
The 'websiteTable' contains 14 columns (website name, website url, password, first name, gender ....and so on) 
I have this test code but it not find anything:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.DataPwdDataSet.websiteTable.Select("Website Name like, Website Url like '" & SearchBox.Text & "'")
End Sub
```

The problem is I need search ALL Keywords from that selected table called 'websiteTable'; so when usr type in SearchBox.Text input any keyword it will display in DataGridView1.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a BindingSource object it will be easier, faster and more safe way to filter the data.
Then the filtering will be like this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = YourBindingsource
YourBindingSource.Filter = "Url like '" & TextBoxSerach.Text & "%'"
```

If you want read a little bit about [binding Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Comment: thx, but Description = Should I change or let it liek that? I dont have any description or i dotn know what you mean

Comment: "use your column name. i have changed it to Url" Column name like "Header Text" OR DataPropertyName ? Sirry Iam newbie and try to learn

Comment: Thanks actually this work: 

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        DataGridView1.DataSource = WebsiteTableBindingSource
        WebsiteTableBindingSource.Filter = "WName like '" & SearchBox.Text & "%'"

    End Sub
 
 But it shows all names but I have 2 problems:
 
 1. How to get back from searchs so it comes back 'like reset'
 2. I want it search exemple name: Peter, BUT I WANT display also 'peter' with small "p"
 
 thanks

Comment: Please help me with my syntax error, I need that search look for ALL COLUMNS name I have 14, so i tried to add Second and this I get: http://postimg.org/image/iair9bzsz/ Thank You friend

Comment: Thanks BUT I have another issue, when I type website name [WName] in search box it find it, BUT when i type username [WUser] It not find and actually it replace the name i type for search IN THE results WName field, WName is Website name. SO if i search for Facebook, IT find ok, but when i type Ted, it show Ted name IN THE PLACE where was Facebook name field :(

Comment: also have a look at this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23459

Comment: Ok so I added combobox and added Items like, Search Names, Search Urls and so on..so what should be the code please? I know like If combobox1.selected.items = "Search Names" then ..and the code you sned BUT it not show and that error still show that EXEPTION in screen :'( omgg

Comment: I made this code BUT IT not working:  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Search in Website URL" Then
            WebsiteTableBindingSource.Filter = "[WName] like '" & SearchBox.Text & "%'"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Search in Username" Then
            WebsiteTableBindingSource.Filter = "[WUser] like '" & SearchBox.Text & "%'"
        End If end sub

Comment: also the exemple of microsoft demo I can not see it is corupted or idk what happens: http://postimg.org/image/7r7df0zt3/

Comment: waitfor my answer a sec.

Comment: use in the buttonSearch: 

 Dim StringFilter As String = String.Empty
        Dim ComboText As String = String.Empty
        Try
            ComboText = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("You didn't make a chooice in the fields")
        End Try

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboText) Then
            StringFilter = ComboText & " like '" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "%'"
            CitiesBindingSource.Filter = StringFilter
        End If

Comment: ok i tested BUT I get only as a results popup msgbox with text "You didn't make a chooice in the fields" so what should i do? the combobox has 13 items, and I selected several and tried to make search in that fields, but still only the msgbox, thanks

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the line with the: ComboText = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString -- Mouse over or add watch to the ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString check the value that it brings. Try to find if the ComboBox1.selectedvalue.ToString is bringing you the right value or the ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString

Comment: how did you add the items on your combobox?

Comment: I select the property on right and added to item collection